# how append key value dictionary python onvif camera

Tags: python

I want to add nested key value to dictionary "continuos_move" but I am having problems. check this

```
print(continuous_move)
continuous_move.Velocity = {'PanTilt': {'x': ''}}
print(continuous_move)
print(continuous_move.Velocity.PanTilt)
```

OUTPUT

```
{
    'ProfileToken': '0',
    'Velocity': None,
    'Timeout': None
}
{
    'ProfileToken': '0',
    'Velocity': {
        'PanTilt': {
            'x': ''
        }
    },
    'Timeout': None
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myuser/Projects/onvif_zeep/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(continuous_move.Velocity.PanTilt)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'PanTilt'
```

I need to create:

```
{
    'ProfileToken': '0',
    'Velocity': {
        'PanTilt': {
            'x': ''
            'y': ''
        }
    },
    'Timeout': None
}
```

I want to control onvif camera https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl#op.ContinuousMove
Then add values like
continuous_move.Velocity.PanTilt.x = value

Comment: Have you tried ```print(continuous_move.Velocity.get("PanTilt")``` ?

Comment: print this {'x': ''} then the continuous_move.Velocity.PanTilt.x = 0 doesnt work. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myuser/Projects/onvif_zeep/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    continuous_move.Velocity.PanTilt.x = 0
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'PanTilt'

Comment: You have to use the [] notation. Then ```continous_move.Velocity["Pantilt"]["x"]``` should work